# Create database project for PostgreSQL in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio

I need to create a database project in Visual Studio 2015 for PostgreSQL databases. Then we can maintain version control of each database object in the form of SQL script file. So, is there any such provision (may be in the form of plug-in) in Visual Studio 2015?

EDITED:
We're already using Team Foundation System (TFS) as our version control system for all of our projects. So, we would like to use the same for Postgres scripts also. Our projects are developed in .Net on Windows OS, even the Postgres is now running on Windows Server. What we want is to use Visual Studio only for creating a database project for Postgres (similar .sqlproj for Microsoft SQL Server) so that we can maintain version history of table schemas in the form of SQL files, build the project and deploy whatever server we need. Hope I have provided enough information now.

Comment: It could be operating system specific, and you might consider switching to a genuine [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (perhaps [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)...) You could version control (perhaps with [git](http://git-scm.com/)...) the dump of the database, or of its schema, or of the script creating it. Notice that your PostGreSQL server could be a remote one (running Linux). Your question (without any [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is off-topic here. Notice that Visual Studio is just an IDE.

Comment: We're already using Team Foundation System (TFS) as our version control system for all of our projects. So, we would like to use the same for PostGres scripts also. Our projects are developed in .Net on Windows OS, even the PostGres is now running on Windows Server. What we want is to use Visual Studio only for creating a database project  for PostGres (similar to SQL Server) so that we can maintain source chageset history, build the project and deploy whatever server we need. Hope I have provided enough information now.

Comment: Post the information in the question not in comments.